# Embed a video into Docusaurus that occupies 100% of the width

Tags: css, reactjs, docusaurus

I'm building [a website](https://www.10studio.tech/docs/prettyFormula/) by [V2 Docusaurus](https://v2.docusaurus.io/).

I want to embed a youtube video into the page. I want the width of the frame to be `100%` of the page. I tried a lot of solutions, but have not found the perfect one. At the moment, i'm using the following code:

```
<iframe width="675" height="380" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_AQXQDjw7Y8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It works well in desktop, but i realize that it does not work well in phone:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a Docusaurus-specific issue.

> `<iframe width="675" ... />`

You're hardcoding a width value which is larger than most mobile device widths, so that's expected. See how the [Flux docs](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/in-depth-overview) does it in https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/docs/In-Depth-Overview.md.

Comment: Interestingly, Gatsby has a plugin to resize iframes which have explicit width/height set. See their plugin, [gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe/). You can see an example on https://gatsby-replication-tufandotio.netlify.app/embed-video-in-mdx/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps setting the width to `100%` instead of `676` didn't work when the question was asked but it definitely works today.